# How to define and deal with interface?

Tags: angular, interface, angular5

I have a interface for city details as follows:

```
export interface CityDetail {
    [index: number]: {
        id?: number,
        name: string,
        latitude?: string,
        longitude?: string,
        current_temperature?: string,
        current_humidity?: string,
        temp_max?: string,
        temp_min?: string,
        current_wind?: string,
        current_wind_pressure?: string,
        current_weather_condition?: string
    };
};
```

This interface I want to define as

```
 const countryClimate: CityDetail = {
                id: items['id'],
                name: items['name'],
                current_temperature: items['main']['temp'],
            };
```

But I am getting error

```
Type '{ id: any; name: any; current_temperature: any; }' is not assignable to type 'CityDetail'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'CityDetail'.ts
```

Can anybody tell me what mistake I did?

Comment: Usually when working with an interface you are supposed to create a class which will implement that interface. You don't instantiate interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think your **items** object like this

```
const items: Item = {
    id: any;
    name: any;
    current_temperature: any;
}
```

You should change item object type or do that:

```
 const countryClimate: CityDetail = {
     id: items['id'] as number,
     name: items['name'] as string,
     current_temperature: items['main']['temp'] as string,
 };
```